# Photon Collision Issue

Tags: user-interface, collision, multiplayer, photon

Alright so I am new to photon and am trying to run it on a game based around being hit once and losing the round. My score, though I think I have it setup correctly, is updating both players. Please note the logic variable connects to the second script. Also, the variable player is your player ID via Photon. Heres code:

MPMovement.cs

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            //This looks for players landing after a jumps, calls correctly to the animator and then
            //Begins to set everything back to the way it was. Still not sure about setting velocity
            //To zero, but why fix what isn't broken, amirite?
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground") || other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                jumpCount = jumps;
                //rbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                anim.SetBool("grounded", true);
                anim.SetBool("jumping", false);
            }
            //This looks for a hit from another player. This will trigger whether it is a standing or crouching hit, as the
            //Results will be the exact same either way it plays out; if someone is hit, they die.
            //On a hit. All hitboxes are shut off (avoid multiple hits) and the win counter goes up.
            //It then notifies the other player they have been hit, sets their dead trigger, and deducts a win.
            //After everything has been set, logic is then sent for to see if the game is over.
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && (other.otherCollider.name == "StandHitBox" || other.otherCollider.name == "CrouchHitBox"))
            {
                SHitBox.enabled = false;
                CHitBox.enabled = false;
                logic.AddWin(playerNum);
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("die");
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Movement>().isDead = true;
                Debug.Log("In");
                StartCoroutine(winWait());
                Debug.Log("Out");
            }
        }
    }
```

MPGameLogic:

```
    //Simply game over logic that checks for a best two of three game
    //I chose to decrement a win on a loss. This is because, at least in a
    //1v1 the games would be ending in about a miniute or two and I want
    //people to be able to enjoy a game with multiple rounds.
    public void CheckWin()
    {
        if (wins == 5)
        {
            Debug.Log("GameOver! " + PhotonNetwork.NickName + " Wins!!!");
            //Need to fix this. Lots should be here to actually exit and leave room
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex - 1);
        }
        newRound();
    }
    void UpdateScore(string player)
    {
        players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++){
            Debug.Log(players[i].name);
            if(players[i].name != "StandHitBox" && players[i].name != "CrouchHitBox")
                if(players[i].GetComponent<MPMovement>().playerNum == player)
                    Debug.Log("Updating for player " + (i % 2) + " via " + winText[i % 2].name);
                    winText[i % 2].GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = wins + "";
        }
    }
    public void AddWin(string player)
    {
        wins++;
        UpdateScore(player);
        CheckWin();
        GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Timer>().Reset();
    }
    public void SubWin(string index)
    {
        if (wins > 0)
        {
            wins--;
            UpdateScore(index);
        }
    }
    //Whenever we go to another round we need the positions to reset
    //This also includes 
    public void newRound()
    {
        player.transform.position = locations[0];
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol the answer is bad programming. This actually does work. If you look in my MPGameLogic file, you will probably notice two if statements missing {} this lead to an error while I had debug statements included in the code. Works perfectly now.